# Dynamic method parameter using Blazor Binding

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to make a paging component by using Blazor. Navigate `First`, `Last`, `Previous` and `Next` are already working. The problem is: I want the user to be able to click on a page number and the NavigateToPage action to be executed by passing the page number.

Here's my attempt:

```html
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 offset-lg-6 text-right">
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-end">
            <li class="page-item @PuedeNavegarPrimeraPagina">
                <a class="page-link" tabindex="-1" @onclick="NavegarHaciaPrimeraPagina">Primera</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item @PuedeNavegarPaginaAnterior">
                <a class="page-link" tabindex="-1" @onclick="NavegarHaciaPaginaAnterior">Anterior</a>
            </li>
            @for (int i = 1; i <= TotalPaginas; i++)
            {
                var clasePaginacionPaginaActual = (PaginaActual == i) ? "disabled" : "";
                <li class="page-item @clasePaginacionPaginaActual"><a class="page-link" @onclick="(() => NavigateToPage(i))">@i</a></li>
            }
            <li class="page-item  @PuedeNavegarPaginaSiguiente">
                <a class="page-link" @onclick="NavegarHaciaPaginaSiguiente">Siguiente</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item  @PuedeNavegarUltimaPagina">
                <a class="page-link" @onclick="NavegarHaciaUltimaPagina">Última</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

The `NavigateToPage` expect the page number, **but the current code always sends the same value for all links, which corresponds to the last value of `i`**. If there are 4 pages, then 5 is the parameter no matter which of the links is clicked.

Any idea of how to get different parameters values?

Comment: Not super familiar with Blazor, so I am not entirely sure about this, hence only leaving it as a comment. With expression functions, you need to close over variables as they are deferred. As a result, it is probable you need to close over `i` inside of your `for` loop. Perhaps, `int pageValue = i;` and then `@onclick="(() => NavigateToPage(pageValue))">` will work.

Comment: That is correct. And it's not a Blazor issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop should contain a local variable like this::

```
@for (int i = 1; i <= TotalPaginas; i++)
            {
                var local = i;
                var clasePaginacionPaginaActual = (PaginaActual == local) ? "disabled" : "";
                <li class="page-item @clasePaginacionPaginaActual"><a class="page-link" @onclick="@(() => NavigateToPage(local))">@i</a></li>
            }
```

This is standard C# behavior where lambda expression @(() => NavigateToPage(local)) has access to a variable and not to the value of the variable. You have to define a variable which is local to the for loop, otherwise your lambda expression will always call NavigateToPage(i) and i is 5 at the end of the loop.

Comment: Totally forgot about local scope! Thanks